# Better choice instead of functions for multiple inserts

Tags: mysql, performance

in my sql database I have a procedure that needs to insert in a table tons of randomly generated records.
Something like this:

```
    insert into table_AAA
SELECT 
, round(X + rand() * 10 - rand() * 10   )
, round(Y + rand() * 10 - rand() * 10   )
FROM db_numbers d /*very big table containing just 1 column with numbers from 1 to 1M*/
limit 100000;
```

it takes 3 seconds, sound reasonable compared to other procedure of my servers.

Then I had to make that if the result of the round () is >=0

To do it I made a function:

```
CREATE   FUNCTION  `fn_normalize`(`p_value` INT) RETURNS int(11)

BEGIN
declare v_output INT;
  IF p_value < 0  THEN
    SET v_output = 0 ;
  ELSE  SET v_output = p_value ;
  END IF;
  RETURN (v_output);  

END
```

and my insert became:

```
insert into table_AAA
SELECT 
, fn_normalize(round(X + rand() * 10 - rand() * 10   ))
, fn_normalize(round(Y + rand() * 10 - rand() * 10   ))
FROM db_numbers d /*very big table containing just 1 column with numbers from 1 to 1M*/
limit 100000;
```

very slow, 10x the original one, probably because the function works on each value individually

I thought to use CASE WHEN:

```
insert into table_AAA
SELECT 
, case when(round(X + rand() * 10 - rand() * 10   )) < 0 then 0 else (round(X + rand() * 10 - rand() * 10   )) end
, case when(round(Y + rand() * 10 - rand() * 10   )) < 0 then 0 else (round(X + rand() * 10 - rand() * 10   )) end
FROM db_numbers d /*very big table containing just 1 column with numbers from 1 to 1M*/
limit 100000;
```

But the else will re-run the rand function, so I cannot be sure is a positive number. Using rand(x) is not an option, because I need the most randomness of values.

Make an update after the insert is even worst.

Am I missing some obvious alternative?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Just curious, what is the point of `X + rand() * 10 - rand() * 10`? Why not simply `X + rand() * 10`? Doesn't make sense to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu can use a subquery:

```
insert into table_AAA
SELECT CASE WHEN v.x<0 THEN 0 ELSE v.x END,
  CASE WHEN v.y<0 THEN 0 ELSE v.y END,
FROM (
SELECT 
 round(X + rand() * 10 - rand() * 10   ) AS x
, round(Y + rand() * 10 - rand() * 10   ) AS y
FROM db_numbers d /*very big table containing just 1 column with numbers from 1 to 1M*/
limit 100000) v;
```

Answer (score 1):

Much simpler (and faster) function body:

```
RETURN GREATEST(0, p_value);
```

Or, applying that to davide's solution:

```
insert into table_AAA
   SELECT 
         GREATEST(0, round(X + rand() * 10 - rand() * 10 )) AS x,
         GREATEST(0, round(Y + rand() * 10 - rand() * 10 )) AS y
      FROM db_numbers d /* table of numbers from 1 to 1M*/
      limit 100000) v;
```